# Avoid getting array indexes via traversing through JSON object

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

**METHOD : -**

```
const getAllKeys = obj => _.union(
  _.keys(obj),
  _.flatMap(obj, o => _.isObject(o) ? getAllKeys(o) : [])
)
```

**SAMPLE JSON :-**

```
const arr = {"{"name":"Base Url","url":"https://kubemanagement-prod.kohls.com"},{"name":"Base Url newwww","url":"https://batman.com"}}

const result = getAllKeys(arr)
console.log(result);
```

**Result : -**

```
["0", "1", "name", "url"]
```

Where in the result set I need to avoid getting array index which is `"0"`and `"1"` Any idea on how to make it possible? I only need the distinct key without array indexes.

*Language : Angular 4 + lodash + javascript*

Comment: Your sample json is invalid in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `_.keys()`

```js
const arr = [{"name":"Base Url","url":"https://kubemanagement-prod.kohls.com"},{"name":"Base Url newwww","url":"https://batman.com"}]

const getAllKeys = obj => _.uniq(
  _.flatMap(obj, o => _.isObject(o) ? _.keys(o) : [])
)

console.log(getAllKeys(arr))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```